# In react how to convert html tags to display inside the htmleditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tags

Hello I have question about how to display html tag inside the HtmlEditor.
First of all, the step that I am taking is storing the html tag to a state from componentdidmount.
Second, I have created the DOMParser and set it to the parsedDocument and I will provide the code
below.

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
 const parsedDocumnet = parser.parseFromString(`
 this.state.contentStore`,
 "text/html"
 );

const textContent = parsedDocumnet.body;
```

Third I have called the textcontent inside the htmleditor. I will also provide code below.

```
 <HtmlEditor height="200px">
    <div
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
       __html: textContent,
       }}
       />
  </HtmlEditor>
```

The outcome of that htmleditor will look like this
[image]

Also if you are wondering what the tag looks like I will also provide picture below this line.

[image]

The tag have table tags on it and I want to display exactly what the tags does. I would be appreciated
if someone can help me to solve this problem. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a parsed DOM object to __html. Try passing your raw html content as a string directly to __html like this

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `this.state.contentStore`,
     }}
/>
```